# How do i access wordpress data/dashboard?

Tags: django, wordpress, web

So, I have created a custom dashboard using Django. I want to access all the fields(activeplugins, active themes, wordpress version, etc) present in my wordpress dashboard and display it in my dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't have default REST endpoint to access admin related data such as plugins, themes. You will have to implement custom endpoint for that. Please refer wordpress devDoc for that. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/